# conj-ing a list of values to a map value in Clojure?

Tags: clojure

What is the idiomatic way of conj-ing a list of values to a map value?

This is the result I want, but the anonymous function looks kind of ugly imo. Is there a better way?

```
> (update-in {:x #{}} [:x] #(apply conj % '(1 2)))
{:x #{1 2}}
```

Comment: As an aside, using a vector (`[1 2]`) is generally more idiomatic than a quoted list (`'(1 2)`) for a literal sequence, as its contents get evaluated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The anonymous function is unnecessary

```
(update-in {:x #{}} [:x] conj 1 2)
;=> {:x #{1 2}}

(update-in {:x #{}} [:x] into [1 2])
;=> {:x #{1 2}}
```

Comment: Another option would be `(update-in {:x #{}} [:x] clojure.set/union #{1 2})`. I prefer this one because the intent is more explicit (add elements to a set).

Comment: I read the question as generic, with a set being just an example collection, but sure.

Answer (score 0):

You should not have to know whether the map `contains?` the key that you are `conj`ing  values to. Adapting your example ...

```
(update-in {} [:x] #(apply conj % '(1 2)))
;{:x (2 1)}
```

... not what you want.

The following

```
(defn assocs [m k coll]
  (assoc m k (into (get m k #{}) coll)))
```

... supplies an empty-set value if no entry for the key exists.

```
(assocs {} :x [1 2])
;{:x #{1 2}}

(assocs {:x #{2}} :x [1 2])
;{:x #{1 2}}
```

You'll find similar code in [clojure.algo.graph](https://github.com/clojure/algo.graph/), for example [here](https://github.com/clojure/algo.graph/blob/03c740c61aecb55225bdad19813e316f44837142/src/main/clojure/clojure/algo/graph.clj#L37). (Warning: the `graph` type only functions in one of the algorithms and otherwise just gets in the way.)